# Toolbar + selection + options all on the same screen

Tags: gui-design

Is this the best way to put all of these on the same page?

EDIT: More info... this function is used to search recorded video.

I have:

1. Camera list
2. A quick search or Date/Time search
3. options for those searches

[image]

[image]

Comment: Camera 1 and 2 are the front and back camera? So there will be just 2 cameras as max? the dates you are loading are the dates of the recorded date+hour of the videos?

Comment: there will bet between 4-64 cameras on the list. The app is connecting remotely to a surveillance DVR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you have it now is great. Why clutter it by trying to do too much at once. I would suggest changing `Quick` to a more expressive saying though. Like `Set time increments` or something shorter.

If you did want to get it all on one page you could just put `Camera one` and `Camera two` as two small tabs at the top and not give them all that screen real estate and then put the calendar at the bottom. I would put the section you expect them to use less at the bottom.